# Remote debugging C++ application with Eclipse GUI

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, windows

I followed the steps in this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/324290/)
 and I manage to debug a binary which resides in linux host from my windows machine from command prompt.

I have gdbserver in linux and I installed gdb with the help of mingw in windows. As I told I can prompt "target remote x.x.x.x:10000 test" to command in windows and debug my test application.

My problem is I can't do the same with eclipse gui, it seems to me it has tones of buttons, options but they make no sense to me.

I am choosing debug_configurations-->C/C++ Remote Application(the only one which allows me to input linux machine ip/port), in "Main" tab to connection I am inputting my linux ip. In same menu under Debugger tab I am inputting my window's gdb path and gdbserver port.

After doing all those I believe I gave enough info to eclipse for connect gdb server but it never enough for eclipse. I am checking gdbserver logs by starting gdbserver with --debug, gdbserver never gets triggered, it does not writes a single line of log. Eclipse even does not starts a connection. But instead it gives me a error like "Error during file upload." which makes no sense to me.

I am using "Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2" . Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the "C/C++ Remote Application" option uses Eclipse's [RDT](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.rdt.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftoc.html) (Remote Development Tools) and [RSE](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html) (Remote System Explorer) to connect, upload, execute, and debug the application itself.  It

If all you want to do is connect to a `gdbserver`, then create a "C/C++ Attach to Application" debug configuration, and under the Debugger tab, set Debugger to gdbserver.

Comment: Short , informative , cool and awsome you saved my day thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error message for other reason on Eclipse version 2019-09 R (4.13.0).
I very recommend to read paragraph "How do I debug a remote application?" from [this great guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#What_is_the_CDT.3F).

It explains which of three remote debugging options you should be using - Automatic Remote Launcher, Manual Remote Launcher and Remote Attach Launcher and how to use each one.

I was using the wrong launcher and hence got the error, while on the remote side `gdbserver` was listening and waiting for a connection. Switching to Manual Remote Launcher solved it.

for example it says:

> If you don't have RSE installed, you cannot use the "Automatic Remote
> Launch"

RSE = Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime

Launcher setting is configured from the bottom of the Remote Debug Configuration window - "Using GDB (DSF) Automatic/Manual Remote Debugging Launcher".